# Big Dilemma With Encryption Public And Private Key Pairs Concept

Tags: php, encryption

I am creating a RESTful API web service and I need a way of implementing public and private key pairs.

I will use some of PHP's built in functions to create my own algo to generate both of the values for the keys.

I just need to understand the concept or logic behind the system in general.

example the client and the server have both public and private key values. Are the keys then combined using another algo on the client side that is decoded on the server side and if matched the resource requested is then shown?

or am I way off them mark? Any links or suggestions would be well apprecciated

Comment: The private key is generated and stored in a keystore on the server. Using the private key, a public key is generated. This public key is provided to others (for instance, a browser) to encrypt the message to send *back* to the server, which can only (hopefully) be decrypted using the private key in the keystore.

Comment: But, the point of a *private* key is **not** to give it out. `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few algorithms that make use of private/public keypairs. The three common uses for them are: encryption/decryption, signing/verifying, and key agreement.

For encryption/decryption, data is encrypted using only the public key, and decrypted using the private key. An example for this is the RSA algorithm.

For signing/validating, data is signed with the private key, and validated with the public key. An example for this is the DSA algorithm.

For key agreement, there are two parties with their public/private keys. The parties exchange their public keys, and a shared secret is generated using the private key, the public key, and  the public key of the opposite end. An example for this is the Diffie-Hellman (DH) algorithm.

As the names suggest, for any party, you never give your private key out. You can safely publish your public key anywhere you want. With only the public key, you cannot perform any of the tasks above that require a private key - and obviously figuring out the private key given a public key is not feasible.

Comment: One of the more challenging aspects of public/private key encryption was to understand that the the public key is given to the sender, who then encodes (encrypts) the message the sender will generate to send back to the receiver (who "owns" the public/private key). So in a way, it's a reverse, with the message sender receiving the public key, and the message receiver sending the public key to receive a future message, and that overall **both** typically trade positions (browser/server, for example).

Comment: And the second is also referred to as non-repudiation, right?

Comment: @JaredFarrish True. The signing operations does two things: validates that the message you send indeed comes from you, and allows the receiver to prove later that it has come from you (the non-repudiation term comes from the latter).

Comment: Thanks for your answers, You have helped me to understand a little more what needs to be done. I think that the DSA algorithm with the signing/validating is what I want to use.

Comment: One question in relation to signing with the private key. Is that basically encoding the request from the client with the private key and the decoding the request on the server side with the same private key?

Comment: @user866190 - The only time you sign with a private key is when the receiver of the message from the sender (who owns the private key) needs to validate the message (they do not, however, decrypt it, it's encrypted typically with envelope encryption using the *receiver's* public key). This is what message signatures are. If it's a message->encrypt->send->decrypt process, the *public key* is used to encrypt, not the private. Please reread my comment below this answer. `:)`